# Assigning another variable from a binding operator in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone please explain the following perl snippet to a novice?

```
my @array = qw/username=admin username=root/; 

foreach my $string (@array) { 
    if ($string =~ /username/) { 
        my ($nextString) = $string =~ /username=(\w+)/; 
        print "It worked, \$nextString is $nextString\n"; 
    } 
}
```

I understand the most of the code, but this part is confusing me:

```
my ($nextString) = $string =~ /username=(\w+)/;
```

It returns the strings "admin" and "root". Why doesn't it return the "username=" portion as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you told it to capture the "word" after `username=`. The match operator in list context returns the string captured by the captures (`()`). If you want `username=admin` to be returned, use

```
my ($nextString) = $string =~ /(username=\w+)/;
```

---

By the way, there's no reason to match twice. Instead of

```
if ($string =~ /username=\w+/) { 
    my ($nextString) = $string =~ /username=(\w+)/; 
    ...
}
```

use

```
if ( my ($nextString) = $string =~ /username=(\w+)/ ) { 
    ...
}
```

It's more efficient, and it avoids code duplication.

Comment: Thanks! The code above was actually a simpler snippet to an already existing script, I just needed to understand this portion. Even better, you gave a more efficient procedure for future use. Kudos!